# Is there a way when doing remote testing (qrcode etc) to control the exposed port?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qr-code, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying something akin to:
testcafe remote tests/dashboards/CustomerTests/myorg.js --qr-code -ports 9999,9998

But that still exposes the following URL:
http://192.168.134.205:58732/browser/connect

Is there any way to control the "58732" part of this?  My internal network is pretty well locked down, and that port # changes every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works correctly with the proper [--ports](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--ports-port1port2) argument (notice double --):

```
testcafe remote test.js --qr-code --ports 9999,9998
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
Connecting 1 remote browser(s)...
Navigate to the following URL from each remote browser.
You can either enter the URL or scan the QR-code.
Connect URL: http://192.168.67.55:9999/browser/connect
```

Comment: Thanks!  That definitely did the trick / I clearly needed more coffee.

Q:  Is there a reason one has to specify at least 2 ports?  (versus just --ports 9999)

Comment: I don't think there's a specific reason. The '--ports' command-line argument was just designed to accept two ports. When one wants to change their ports, it is likely that they will change both ports, but not just a single port.